# Cannot cast from BigDecimal to String in jasper (weird error //$JR_EXPR_ID=18$)

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a jrxml file which has a field of BigDecimal value and when I try to execute the report. I get an error called " Cannot cast from BigDecimal to String in jasper". Im doing the report using ireport 5.6.0, and I get a weird error like this,

```
1. Cannot cast from BigDecimal to String
            value = (java.lang.String)(((java.math.BigDecimal)variable_variable1.getValue())); //$JR_EXPR_ID=18$
                    <----------------------------------------------------------------------->
2. Cannot cast from BigDecimal to String
            value = (java.lang.String)(((java.math.BigDecimal)variable_variable1.getOldValue())); //$JR_EXPR_ID=18$
                    <-------------------------------------------------------------------------->
3. Cannot cast from BigDecimal to String
            value = (java.lang.String)(((java.math.BigDecimal)variable_variable1.getEstimatedValue())); //$JR_EXPR_ID=18$
                    <-------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
3 errors
```

I tried to change the expression class. but nothing seems to work. I need the value to get the sum and also as a field.

Comment: Use `toString` instead of casting.

Comment: I need the bigDecimal value for some calculations within the report

Comment: You might want to show some pivotal parts of your report definition. If you need the value both as string and as decimal, you may use a variable to hold the second representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a field e.g `$F{ID}` with field `class=java.math.BigDecimal`.As you want to use this field as a string as well as decimal;

You can create two variables variable1 with variable `Class=java.math.BigDecimal` with Variable Expression as `$F{ID}`

and create another variable variable2 with variable `Class=java.lang.String` with Variable Expression as `$F{ID}.toPlainString()`

Answer (score 0):

When I removed tag "printWhenExpression" for that text field with error, the error did not show again.